# groupby pandas and putting values as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like some help please.
I have this Dataframe :[Input:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HLyw.png)

and I would like to groupby by code and date and put all the Id values as columns with the corresponding values of the key (code, date)
like this :

[Output :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIBlw.png)

Thank you for your help !